# Why is this QoS jetty-filter not working?

Tags: java, solr, jetty, throttling, rate-limiting

We want to apply the [QoS Jetty Filter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/qos-filter.html) to our Solr 6.5 servers so that any rate higher than the benchmarked rate is rejected outrightly.

The required jar files are present:

```
/app/solr6/server/lib/jetty-servlets*.jar
/app/solr6/server/lib/jetty-util*.jar
```

And the XML file where we can add the configuration for the filter is at:

```
/app/solr6/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Solr runs with `-Djetty.home=/app/solr6/server` and I have confirmed that if we remove the above XML file, solr fails to start in jetty. So the XML file above is the correct location for putting the QoS filter.

Problem is that I am unable to get the QoS filter up and running with the following config:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>QoSFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>maxRequests</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>waitMS</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>suspendMS</param-name>
    <param-value>500</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>QoSFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have a single node Solr running with the above configuration but no rate limiting seems to be happening. I have a client with 30 threads (running on 8 cores machine) and I do not see any reduction in queries/second when I apply the above filter on the Solr server.

How do I know the filter is working and throttling the rate of my requests at all?

Comment: Were you able to throttle the request?

Comment: Facing the same issue with Solr 7.7.2....QoS filter is not respected and Jetty allows more than maxRequests number of parallel requests. Were you able to get around this?